# Catkin command not found

Tags: ros, catkin

I have installed ROS indigo and gazebo2 packages in Ubuntu 14.04.5. When I try to use catkin command, I get:

**catkin_init_workspace : command not found**

So, I tried to install catkin, it displays that **ros-indigo-catkin is the latest version.**

All I did was,

```
$ sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-desktop-full

$ sudo apt-get install gazebo2.<They're installed perfectly>
```

After this, I am getting catkin issue.

Help needed. Someone please find a way to fix this issue.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Probably you forgot to [set up the environment](http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Ubuntu) after installing ROS.

```
$ echo "source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash" >> ~/.bashrc
$ source ~/.bashrc
```

Then, I will assume you want to create a package, so you can follow these steps:

```
$ mkdir -p path_to_my_workspace/workspace_name/src
$ cd path_to_my_workspace/workspace_name/src
$ catkin_init_workspace
$ cd path_to_my_workspace/workspace_name/
$ catkin_make
$ source path_to_my_workspace/workspace_name/devel/setup.bash
```

After running these commands your workspace is created, so now you can start adding packages.

Comment: The first two lines will not work in a Dockerfile. See [Docker - Dockerfile: /bin/bash: catkin_init_workspace / catkin_make: command not found](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/a/21960/27423). The answer here is not wrong, since the question is not a Docker question. It just took me a while to find out that there is a difference, probably it is not the same in an image if you *source the .bashrc* and if you *source a setup.bash in one go*.

Answer (score 35):

Had almost the same issue when i tried to run this command (please refer to the pics attached).

```
$ catkin build
```

[Screenshot for solution applied to solve catkin build error](https://acutronicrobotics.com/docs/products/mara/motionplanning/tutorials/ros/gettingstarted)
I solved it by installing catkin ROS build system using the command below (references attached in the links and pictures attached). [Screenshot for catkin build error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzRqS.png)

```
$ sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-catkin python-catkin-tools
```

Comment: This solved it for me. I was missing python-catkin-tools specifically.

Comment: This helped me as well.  FYI, "sudo apt-get install ros-$ROS_DISTRO-catkin python-catkin-tools " will run against whatever ROS version you have.

Comment: For noetic and later that use Python 3 this answer is not correct. See @drewlufkin answer below what is correct (install Python 3 versions of these packages)

Answer (score 23):

If the workspace is setup, you properly sourced ROS as stated above, and if catkin_make works, but catkin build doesn't work do this:

```
sudo apt install python3-catkin-tools python3-osrf-pycommon
```

This is a catkin-tools dependency which was delinked in Ubuntu 20.04 so it has to be manually specified to be installed.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you didn't install "catkin ROS build system"

You can install it using the following command for ROS **Melodic**:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-melodic-catkin python-catkin-tool
```

**or** for ROS **kinetic**

```
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-catkin python-catkin-tool
```

If you want to **create a ROS package**, you can use: `catkin create pkg myworkSpace --catkin-deps rospy`
this command will create a ROS workspace with a source folder, CMakeLists.txt and package.xml

**or use**

```
mkdir catkin
cd catkin
catkin create pkg myworkSpace --catkin-deps rospy
```

**The provided commands are for Python.** So, make sure to modify it for Cpp if you want so.